# Exporting layer to shapefile using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis

I´m using python in QGIS 2.2 and struggling with an error trying this:

```
# create layer from text
_vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(_ur1, "raw", "delimitedtext")
```

works fine
but:

```
# export layer to shape
_writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat\
(_vlayer,"hoppla.shp","utf-8",None,"ESRI Shapefile")
```

... ends up wiht error code "3" - according to documentation:"ErrCreateLayer".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's all about user rights.

Just changed to a directory I'm allowed to write, everything works fine.

```
_writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(_vlayer,r"C:/Users/myName/xx/hoppla.shp","utf-8",None,"ESRI Shapefile")
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and figured out, that there seems to be a bug in the class  QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat

I was pretty sure that I had permission for the folder and in my case this did NOT work anyway:
`QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat\
(layer,"C:\Users\Myname\Desktop\test\hoppla.shp","utf-8",None,"ESRI Shapefile")`
although the folder 'test' existed on my desktop and had all rights.

Now the most absurd thing to try was to make "test" upper case --> "Test"
`QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat\
(layer,"C:\Users\Myname\Desktop\`**T**`est\hoppla.shp","utf-8",None,"ESRI Shapefile")`
and now it worked! Further I tried to check the folders before the last folder where the file was to be saved in for case sensitivity and if I changed (in this code example) 'Desktop' to lower case ('desktop') it worked!

On the other hand something like `QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(temp_layer, "C:\Users\Myname\desktop\test1\test2\wasneues4.shp", "utf-8", None, "ESRI Shapefile")` would NOT work, but `QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(temp_layer, "C:\Users\Myname\desktop\Test1\Test2\wasneues4.shp", "utf-8", None, "ESRI Shapefile")` with both T's upper case works! Very weird...

Hopefully this was not driving too many people crazy ^^ I will report this bug.

My QGis Version: 2.8.2, so not the latest.

Comment: But the problem still exists in the 2.12.1 version ;)

Comment: Just saw this: use RAW strings or Python will escape your characters: `\t` is a tab, which is obviously not allowed in filenames... Not a bug. `r"C:\Users\Myname\Desktop\Test\hoppla.shp"` sure works as expected..

Comment: As @nnolde said, you cannot use \t or \n, because they are reserved as tab and new line, respectively. The best practice to use the forward slash to selarate folders, i.e., `"C:/users/myname/desktop/test/hoopla.shp"` or to add the raw processing character `r` before the string quotations. The former is compatible with windows, mac, and linux.