# Creating permanent vector layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, layers, vector, memory, storage

I am currently creating a vector layer like following:

```
outLayer = QgsVectorLayer('Linestring?crs='+ crs, 'graph_with_azimuth_ogr' , 'memory')
```

The outLayer is now stored in memory, which means it only stores the layer temporarily. If I restart QGIS, the layer will be deleted again.

*My question is:* How is it possible to create a vector layer which is permanently stored or which storage provider do I need to achieve this?

I have already tried it with the `"ogr"` storage provider, but it does not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps this post might help: [Exporting layer to shapefile using PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/127749/exporting-layer-to-shapefile-using-pyqgis).

Comment: Can you not just substitute a file path where it says 'memory'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Joseph suggested in the comments, the solution is to add the following line
to your python script:

```
_writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(outLayer ,r"C:/Users/yourUser/yourPath/something.shp","utf-8",None,"ESRI Shapefile")
```

This line will export your outputlayer into a shapefile. If you want to export it into another format, you will have to specify it (in the last parameter).

Thank you Joseph!