# Saving shapefile with QgsVectorFileWriter

Tags: pyqgis, shapefile, qgis-3, qgis-processing

I've tried to create a vector file (shapefile) with `QgsVectorFileWriter`. This is my code:

```
path = "/home/camilocorredor/Documentos/ANT/4_Abril/File.shp"    
options = QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions()
options.driverName = "ESRI Shapefile"
    
QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV2(layer_test, path, QgsCoordinateTransformContext(), options)
```

The vector file never is created on the folder.

Any suggesting?

Comment: Look this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/127749/exporting-layer-to-shapefile-using-pyqgis

Comment: check user permissions or run qgis using `sudo qgis`, then, try again.